# Table doesn't display Chrome

Tags: php, css, html-table

I have one of the weirdest problem I've ever faced. I have a website used by  hundreds of people and I have a very strange issue. My code is the following (sample and example) :

```
<div id="DivTHead">
    <!-- THIS doesn't display -->
    <table id="THead">
        <tr align="center">
            <td class="ID">ID</td> 
            <td class="Date_Hour">Date and hour</td> 
            <td class="User">User</td> 
            ........
        </tr>
    </table>    
</div>

<div id="DivTBody">
    <!-- This is working fine -->
    <table id="TBody" border="1">
        <?php
            $SQL = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM rapport where ID = $ID ORDER BY Date_heure "); 
            while($ligne = $SQL -> fetch())
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo "<td class=\"ID\">".$ligne['ID']."</td>";
                echo "<td class=\"Date_Hour\">".date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($ligne['Date_Hour']))."</td>";
                echo "<td class=\"User\">".$ligne['User']."</td>";
                ........
            }
        ?>  
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that `<div id="DivTHead">` doesn't display. If I inspect the element, it appers, but there isn't anything on screen. There is something weird... Not everyone have this problem. I'm facing it, but I asked dozens of people and none of them is facing this problem. I obviously cleared my cache and everything but still this problem. Here's my `.css` but it looks fine :

```
table, th, td {
   /* border: 1px solid black;*/
    text-align: center;
}

div#DivTBody {

    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height: 350px;

}

table#tbody {

    width: 100%;

}

div#DivTHead {
    width: 100%;
}

table#THead{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:none;
    width: 98.8%;
}

.ID {
    width: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}
.Date_Hour{
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
.User{
    width: 15%;
}
```

It is working fine on IE and Mozilla. Why is there this problem and how to avoid it?

Comment: Check for missed closing-tags. We are not able to find errors that are not reproducable! So either you find an option to make it possible for us to reproduce it, or you have to look for yourself.

Comment: works for me in chrome

Comment: I suggest creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us that reproduces your problem. This will allow us to debug it and see what's going on.

Comment: As I said, I asked dozen of ppl and I'm the only one facing that. If this was a problem such as closing tag I surely shouldn't be the only one. I can _find an option to make it possible for us to reproduce it_ because I don't know where it comes from, this is why I asked though and ofc I've ever looked for myself otherwise I shouldn't have asked

Comment: @imGaurav I'm not surprised, not everyone is facing this problem..

Comment: @icecub the fiddle works fine..

Comment: do you have any chrome extensions installed, that manipulate DOM? I once had an issue with adblock, that hid elements with certain names/classes/whatever. Try disabling such extensions.

Comment: @Dygestor That was adblock... It's saying that it blocks nothing but since I disable it, the table comes back... I don't know why... Thank you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling your extensions in Chrome. If you are the only one facing this problem in Chrome, it must be your browser blocking content somehow.